Newton interpolation with no error?
Let's look at $f=x^2+2x+1$ and try to interpolate it with the given points $(1,4) (2,9)$.
$P(x)=f(1)+f[1,2](x-1)=5x-1$.
$f[x_0, x_1,...]$ are the divided differences:
$f[x_0]=f(x_0)$
$f[x_0,x_1]= \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$
$f[x_0,...,x_n]= \frac{f[x_1,...,x_n]-f[x_0,...,x_{n-1}]}{x_n-x_0}$
$E(x)=f[1,2,x](x-1)(x-2)=\frac{f^3(\xi)}{3!}(x-1)(x-2)=0$ for any $\xi\in(1,2)$
Why there is no error? It doesn't make sense

What does the notation $f[1,2]$ mean, please?

$f[1,2]=(f(2)-f(1))/(2-1)$, I suppose?

I'm not sure what the confusion is here. There are two points; the straight line $P(x)=5x-1$ goes through both, which is why there's no error.

But the solution goes through the interpolation points always, thats all the point isn't it? So it's like saying the solution always has no error

You read the relation between number of nodes and derivative wrong. With $n+1$ nodes you get the $n$th derivative at some midpoint,
$$
f[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]=\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}
$$
for some $\xi$ in the convex hull of $x_0,x_1,...,x_n$. Your remainder term has three nodes, thus $n=2$. And the second derivative is non-zero.

What a silly mistake. Anyway, I just added $(3,16)$ to the calculation and the new interpolation is equal to the function. Does it make sense I can interpolate the entire function with no error just by knowing 3 points?

Yes, because two degree $n$ polynomials that have the same value at $n+1$ points are equal.
